# How to copy a class object to another class object

Tags: objective-c, class, copy, shallow-copy

Assume Fraction with properties int num and int denom and NSString *label. All through @property. Suppose we provide copy method (not through NSCopying protocol) so we can do

Fraction *g = [Fraction some initializer here];

Fraction *f = [g copy];

Show exactly what is needed in Fraction.h and Fraction.m to get this shallow.

```
-(void) copy: (Fraction*) f {
    self.num = f.num;
    self.denom = f.denom;
    self.label = f.label;
}
```

Gives me error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: This smells like either a very old tutorial or an example not derived from a Foundation base class.

Answer (score 0):

The copy method you are trying to invoke is part of an existing instance,
It should return a new instance as a result.

```
-(Fraction *) copy {
    return [Fraction alloc] initWithNum:self.num denom:self.denom label:self.label];
}
```

Comment: How can it return that when it's a void return type?

Comment: @user3436529 It can't;  but -copy should *never return (void)*.   See:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/  Why are you trying to copy an object without simply implementing NSCopying in the recommended, well documented, pattern?

Comment: @user3436529 - Thanks I missed that when copy/paste. Fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

Your question has caused some confusion due to the choice of names.

In Objective-C there is a standard method `copy` - it is implemented by `NSObject` - which returns a brand new object which is a *copy*, or a *clone*, of the existing object.

Your title:

> How to copy a class object to another class object

could be read as you wishing to *overwrite* an existing object with the values of another one, and your `copy:` method does exactly that:

```
-(void) copy: (Fraction*) f {
    self.num = f.num;
    self.denom = f.denom;
    self.label = f.label;
}
```

this *replaces/overwrites* the values of the current (`self`) object's properties with the values of another object's properties (`f`). Calling it `copy:` in Objective-C is a bad choice due to the existence of `copy` which creates a new object.

Your code errors as you call `copy`, not your own `copy:`. Try instead:

```
Fraction *g = [Fraction some initializer here]; // your original object
Fraction *f = [Fraction new]; // another object, with some default values

[f copy:g]; // set f's properties from g's
```

This should work but is confusing as (a) it is called `copy:` and (b) it doesn't actually copy the `label` property at all but *shares* the same object between `f` & `g`. If that object is immutable (`NSString`) that won't make any difference, but if it is mutable (`NSMutableString`) then mutating `g`'s `label` will also mutate `f`'s.\

If you must do this maybe call your method `reinitFrom:`, or something, rather than `copy:`.

HTH